# jQuery: function error & dynamic content doesn't work on Safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, dynamic

I'm trying to understand why sometimes my code works and sometimes not.

First, I have this function that open or close a tchat finder:

```
$(function(){    
    $(document).on("click", "a.tchat_open", function(){
        var uid_target = $(this).attr("rel");

        load_tchat('open', uid_target);

    });

    $(document).on("click", "a.tchat_close", function(){
        var uid_target = $(this).attr("rel");

        load_tchat('close', uid_target);
    });
});
```

But when I put this function above the previous code, the previous code doesn't work:

```
function load_wall() {
    $("#display_wall").html("Loading...");
    $.ajax({
        url:"/scripts/ajax/load_wall.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            $("#display_wall").html(data.content);
        },
        error: function(resultat, statut, erreur){
            console.log(resultat);
            console.log(erreur);
        }
    });
}
```

I can understand why, and when I pass an argument to my function, sometimes it works, sometimes not... I think I didn't understand something with jQuery.

Then, I have a problem on my dynamic content which should be display in this div after clicking on my link .tchat_open. The JSON message is shown:

[image: JSON console message]

But nothing happened in my div. It works on Chrome browser, but not on Safari... What difference is there?

Here is my load_tchat() function:

```
function load_tchat(method_call, uid_target) {      
    $.ajax({
        url:"/scripts/ajax/load_tchat.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "method_call="+method_call+"&tchat_status=close&uid_target="+uid_target,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);

            if(data.tchat_operation == 'open') {

                $("#frameChat").html(data.tchat_content);

                // open tchat --- this doesn't make appear my finder
                frameChat.classList.remove("Espace-Chat-Ferme");
                frameChat.classList.add("Espace-Chat");
            }
        },
        error: function(resultat, statut, erreur){
            console.log(resultat);
            console.log(erreur);
        }
    });

}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To embed an image, add a ! infront of the [] - Please rewrite `But when I put this function above, it doesn't work:` - what function above what code?

Comment: I can't embed an image yet, I don't have enough points. 
@mplungjan I'll rewrite this sentence.

Comment: What is in the data.content and what was the content of display_wall? If the links in the display_wall have class="tchat_close", the will not react to the code you have in tchat_open links. You may want to change `$(document).on("click", "a.tchat_open", function(){
        var uid_target = $(this).attr("rel");` to `$(document).on("click", "a.tchat_open", function(e){ e.preventDefault();
        var uid_target = $(this).attr("rel");`

Comment: I tried it, but in Safari my tchat still doesn't appear. It seems that the Espace-Chat did nothing.